# Spring Boot: Getting metrics from KafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am using KafkaTemplate to write messages to Kafka. I would like to gather some metrics from KafkaTemplate. I am using MicroMeter in my project for metrics collection. How can I expose KafkaTemplate metrics via MeterRegistry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on this right now and expect to issue a pull request today.

Some basic metrics were added to the template recently but what I am working on will expose the complete producer and consumer metrics supported by Micrometer.

Comment: Great! Please let us know when we can test it.

Comment: @Gary - what spring-kafka release we can expect micrometer Kafka Template metrics?  Thanks!

Comment: 2.5. The release candidate is due next Wednesday but you can try 2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT now.